# iOS Facebook integration shows 'App Not Setup' error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am having Facebook login in my iOS App. After following all the steps from developer.facebook.com and successful integration I can see a button in my view on clicking that button it redirects to safari and asking for fb username and password but after logging in it shows 'App Not Setup' error. Here I have 3 questions

1. I want everything to load inside the app itself
2. I don't want the FB login button, I want to load the FB page on viewdidload/appear
3. Whats the reason for "App not Setup" error. I want to test with successful loginenter

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There might be various reasons for  "App not setup" like
Check your plist file where you are entering 'FacebookAppID' and URL string
a)check your facebook app id 
b)check your URL String facebook app id has prefix 'fb'
c)Check your bundle id i.e com.yourapp.com is properly set on facebook app settings or not.
d) Check you have entered all correct information in app settings of your facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't strictly need to use Facebook SDK you could use the `Social.framework`. That way you wouldn't have to worry about the bundle id or Facebook App ID.

Here's a sample code to show how it works:

```
SLComposeViewController *slComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

[slComposeViewController setInitialText:MyText];
[slComposeViewController setTitle:MyTitle];

if (![slComposeViewController addURL:url]) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to add url");
}

[self presentViewController:slComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

//Check the result
slComposeViewController.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
    {
        switch (result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                //Do something
                break;

            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                //Do something
                break;
        }
    };

//If iOS < 7.0 dismiss the viewcontroller

NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

if ([version floatValue] < 7.0)
{
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{   
           [slComposeViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
                // Do something
            }];
        });
}
```

Comment: This is for posting in Facebook. I want login